# Function to create dynamic bins in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, binning

I have pandas DataFrame of numeric columns. This data does not contain any zeros(0).

I have defined a function that creates integer bins as follows

```
 1. -1 for all negative values 
 2. Bin width (e.g. 1000000) upto threshold (e.g. 20000000)
 3. After the threshold (e.g. 20000000), it will dynamically size bins to contain 1% of the total count or NOBS(No. of Observations) 
i.e. if NOBS is going below 1% of total NOBS then it will dynamically adjust the bin width such that it will be approx 1% of total NOBS.
```

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Reproducible example
rng = np.random.default_rng(42)
a = rng.integers(-1687500000, 0, 5000)
b = rng.integers(0, 20000000, 25000)
c = rng.integers(20000000, 56956420100000, 4149)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': np.concatenate([a, b, c])})

def dynamic_binning(df_, col_, first_bin, first_bin_label, bin_width, threshold):

    # Create bins
    m = df_[col_] > threshold
    q = np.linspace(0, 1, 100 * sum(m) // len(df_))

    bins = [-np.inf] + np.arange(first_bin, threshold+1, bin_width).tolist()
    bins += df_.loc[m, col_].quantile(q).tolist()[1:]

#     df_.loc[df_[col_]<=first_bin] = first_bin

    df_bins_ = (pd.cut(df_[col_].dropna(), bins, labels=False, right=False).sub(abs(first_bin_label)+1)
                    .value_counts().rename('NOBS')
                    .sort_index().rename_axis('Bins').reset_index()
                    .assign(Percentage=lambda x: x['NOBS'] / len(df_) * 108))
    return df_bins_
```

Calling the function

```
dynamic_binning(df, 'Col1', 0, 0, 1000000, 20000000)
```

The output of the function

```
    Bins    NOBS    Percentage
0   -1.0    5000    15.813054555038216
1   0.0     1274    4.0291663006237375
2   1.0     1169    3.6970921549679345
3   2.0     1287    4.070280242466836
4   3.0     1241    3.924800140560485
5   4.0     1296    4.098743740665905
6   5.0     1246    3.940613195115523
7   6.0     1288    4.073442853377844
8   7.0     1201    3.798295704120179
9   8.0     1289    4.076605464288852
10  9.0     1174    3.712905209522973
11  10.0    1273    4.02600368971273
12  11.0    1246    3.940613195115523
13  12.0    1277    4.0386541333567605
14  13.0    1292    4.086093297021875
15  14.0    1259    3.9817271369586225
16  15.0    1276    4.035491522445753
17  16.0    1200    3.7951330932091714
18  17.0    1242    3.9279627514714925
19  18.0    1204    3.807783536853202
20  19.0    1266    4.003865413335676
21  20.0    378     1.195466924360889
22  21.0    377     1.1923043134498814
23  22.0    377     1.1923043134498814
24  23.0    377     1.1923043134498814
25  24.0    377     1.1923043134498814
26  25.0    377     1.1923043134498814
27  26.0    377     1.1923043134498814
28  27.0    377     1.1923043134498814
29  28.0    377     1.1923043134498814
30  29.0    377     1.1923043134498814
31  30.0    377     1.1923043134498814
```

In the above example, 20 Bins -1, 0, 1, 2,3,......, 19 are till threshold i.e. 20000000. Bins 20, 21, 22,...30 are dynamic bins as per the third condition mentioned above.

I'm facing issues while using this function for the following cases

1. `first_bin = -10000000, bin_width = 500000, threshold = 5000000`

Calling dynamic_binning function

`dynamic_binning(df, 'Col2', -10000000, -20, 500000, 10000000)`

In this case, 20 Bins `-20, -19, -18,.....-1, 0, 1, 2, .....9` are till threshold i.e. `10000000`. Bins `10, 11, 12,...` are dynamic bins as per the third condition mentioned above. But I need to use this code `df_.loc[df_[col_]<=first_bin] = first_bin` before `df_bins_ = (pd.cut(....` otherwise it creates two bins at the start i.e. -21 and -20 instead of -20 which includes values `<=10000000`

2. If I use `first_bin = 0, bin_width = 0.1, threshold = 3`
   Calling dynamic_binning function
   `dynamic_binning(df, 'Col3', 0, 0, 0.1, 3)`
   In this case, `df['Col3']` values range from -0.281 to 1.922

I get the following error

```
ValueError: bins must increase monotonically
```

3. Getting upper and lower limits of each bin (including dynamic bins) in a new column (bin_labels) e.g. -inf - 0, 0 - 1, 1 - 2, 2 - 3.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this version:

```
def dynamic_binning(df_, col_, first_bin, first_bin_label, bin_width, threshold):

    # Create bins
    m = df_[col_] > threshold
    q = np.linspace(0, 1, 100 * sum(m) // len(df_))

    bins = [-np.inf] + np.arange(first_bin, threshold+1, bin_width).tolist()
    bins += df_.loc[m, col_].quantile(q).tolist()[1:]
    
    df_bins_ = (pd.cut(df_[col_].dropna(), bins, labels=False, right=False)
                  .value_counts().rename('NOBS'))

    # Fix missing bins
    idx = pd.RangeIndex(df_bins_.index.min(), df_bins_.index.max(), name='Bins')

    df_bins_ = (df_bins_.reindex(idx, fill_value=0).reset_index()
                        .assign(Percentage=lambda x: x['NOBS'] / len(df_) * 108,
                                Bins=lambda x: x['Bins'].astype(int) + first_bin_label))

    return df_bins_
```

However, your first call should be `dynamic_binning(df, 'Col1', 0, -1, 1000000, 20000000)` to be consistent.

```
>>> dynamic_binning(df, 'Col1', 0, 0, 1000000, 20000000)
    Bins  NOBS  Percentage
0      0  5000   15.813055
1      1  1274    4.029166
2      2  1169    3.697092
3      3  1287    4.070280
4      4  1241    3.924800
5      5  1296    4.098744
6      6  1246    3.940613
7      7  1288    4.073443
8      8  1201    3.798296
9      9  1289    4.076605
10    10  1174    3.712905
11    11  1273    4.026004
12    12  1246    3.940613
13    13  1277    4.038654
14    14  1292    4.086093
15    15  1259    3.981727
16    16  1276    4.035492
17    17  1200    3.795133
18    18  1242    3.927963
19    19  1204    3.807784
20    20  1266    4.003865
21    21   378    1.195467
22    22   377    1.192304
23    23   377    1.192304
24    24   377    1.192304
25    25   377    1.192304
26    26   377    1.192304
27    27   377    1.192304
28    28   377    1.192304
29    29   377    1.192304
30    30   377    1.192304

>>> dynamic_binning(df, 'Col1', -10000000, -20, 500000, 10000000)
    Bins  NOBS  Percentage
0    -20  4969   15.715014
1    -19     2    0.006325
2    -18     1    0.003163
3    -17     2    0.006325
4    -16     2    0.006325
..   ...   ...         ...
82    62   355    1.122727
83    63   355    1.122727
84    64   355    1.122727
85    65   355    1.122727
86    66   355    1.122727

[87 rows x 3 columns]

>>> dynamic_binning(df, 'Col1', 0, 0, 0.1, 3)
     Bins  NOBS  Percentage
0       0  5000   15.813055
1       1     0    0.000000
2       2     0    0.000000
3       3     0    0.000000
4       4     0    0.000000
..    ...   ...         ...
118   118   347    1.097426
119   119   347    1.097426
120   120   347    1.097426
121   121   347    1.097426
122   122   347    1.097426

[123 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Your modified function is working fine for `dynamic_binning(df, 'Col1', 0, -1, 1000000, 20000000)`. However, for `dynamic_binning(df, 'Col1', -10000000, -20, 500000, 10000000)` NOBS of the first two records should be binned under the first bin i.e. NOBS of -20 and -19 should be binned under -20. NOBS of the -18 bin should belong to -19,  NOBS of the -17 bin should belong to -18, and so on. The output of your modified function is https://imgur.com/EwSVrbj  Expected output is https://imgur.com/9ouefLG .

Comment: For the second case, `dynamic_binning(df, 'Col3', 0, -1, 0.1, 3)` It is throwing an error `ValueError: bins must increase monotonically`. In this case, df['Col3'] values range from -0.281 to 1.922. For the third case, I just need the new column to be created in the existing dataframe which has `bin labels` i.e. bin range such as `-inf - 0, 0 - 1, 1 - 2, 2 - 3.........`

Comment: Also, if there are any missing bins, for instance, `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 11, 12........` then it should insert the missing bins `6, 7, 10` and insert 0 values for `NOBS` column.

Comment: Could you please modify the function as per the above 3 comments?

Comment: @Suhas_Pote. I fixed code for missing bins. However I can't reproduce the exception about "bins must increase monotonically" so I'm not able to fix this.

Comment: I think I found the issue of bins for `dynamic_binning(df, 'Col3', 0, -1, 0.1, 3)` pasting the bins getting created for mentioned function call i.e. `bins +=.....` in the next comment. I'm `ValueError: bins must increase monotonically` because bins should be in increasing order `...... , 3.6, 3.7, 3.8000000000000003, 3.9000000000000004, 3.217874, 3.44, 3.684588, 3.96, 4.3, .....` there is a drop in bins when we merge the output of `[-np.inf] + np.arange(first_bin, threshold+1, bin_width).tolist()` with `df_.loc[m, col_].quantile(q).tolist()[1:]` for `dynamic_binning(df, 'Col3', 0, -1, 0.1, 3)`

Comment: Bins of `dynamic_binning(df, 'Col3', 0, -1, 0.1, 3)` are `[-inf, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.300000000004, 0.4, 0.5, 0.600000001, 0.70000000001, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.200000000002, 1.3, 1.40000000001, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7000000002, 1.8, 1.9000000000000001, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 2.300000003, 2.400000004, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8000000000000003, 2.9000000000000004, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3000000000000003, 3.4000000000000004, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8000000000000003, 3.9000000000000004, 3.217874, 3.44, 3.684588, 3.96, 4.3, 4.73040825, 5.246687, 5.804751, 6.589519, 7.714112, 9.03, 11.370693, 14.962406, 21.879876, 43.65881375, 243441.0]`

Comment: FYI the stats of `'Col3'` ----> `count 183343.000 
mean 23.656
std 2010.844
min 0.000
25% 0.606
50% 1.170
75% 2.251
max 243441.000`

Comment: I tried sorting bins using `bins.sort()` but it is producing incorrect dynamic bins

Comment: How can I reproduce your Col3? I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Stats of `'Col3'` ----> `count 183343.000  mean 23.656 std 2010.844 min 0.000 25% 0.606 50% 1.170 75% 2.251 max 243441.000`  I used `df['Col3'].describe()` to get this stats.

Comment: If I replace `1` with `bin_width` in `bins = [-np.inf] + np.arange(first_bin, threshold+1, bin_width).tolist()` then I'm not getting any error. So, it will be `bin_width` in `bins = [-np.inf] + np.arange(first_bin, threshold+bin_width, bin_width).tolist()`